# Showing that a plane is a T-invariant subspace of $\Bbb R^3$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Prove: Let $T: \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^n$ be a linear isometry. Then $T(u)T(v)$ = uv for all $u,v \in \Bbb R^n$.

I think I can assume that $||T(u) - T(v)|| = ||u - v||$. I also know that $uv = \frac{1}{2}(||u+v||^2 - ||u||^2 - ||v||^2)$.

I have tried numerous ways to show this is true but I am stuck at how to relate the the distance $||u-v||$ and $T(u)T(v) = u v$.

Prove: Let $T: \Bbb R^3 \to \Bbb R^3$ be a linear isometry. Supposed that $u \in \Bbb R^3$ is an eigenvector for T. Then the plane $u ^ = \{ v \in \Bbb R^3: uv =0 \}$ is a T-invariant subspace of $\Bbb R^3$.

I have a general idea of what an invariant subspace is but, I don't know what to do with it to solve this part.

Answer (score 1):

As T is linear isometry we have, $||T(u)-T(v)||^2=||u-v||^2$, expand this and use the fact that $||T(u)||=||u||$ and $||T(v)||=||v||$ to get the desired result.